# Swift PickerView label

Tags: swift, ios9, uipickerview

I have picker view of weight values. I wanna to add "Kg" on right side of selected value. How can i archive it?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved by putting inside picker view a label and center it with auto layout in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

try it. Hope it help.

```
    let kg = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 10,10))
    kg.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 23)
    kg.text = "kg"
    kg.sizeToFit()
    kg.frame = CGRectMake(pickerView.bounds.width / 4 + kg.bounds.width, pickerView.bounds.height / 2 - (kg.bounds.width / 2) ,kg.bounds.width,kg.bounds.height)
    pickerView.addSubview(kg)
```

Comment: Thx. Where should i Add this?

Comment: put it in a func and call it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/83ik4mlev/) Can u help me to center it? I manage to center it for iph5 but when I lauch 6 or 4 its not centered.